# Working with custom PowerShell TypeNames entries and parameters

Tags: powershell

I often get data from the database and adjust the typenames collection of the datarow objects to reflect the "type" of data that the row represents.  For instance, if I'm looking at datarows which represent computer objects, I might add "MDS__COMPUTER" to the end of the TypeNames collection.  I do the same thing with PSObjects that I create using New-Object.

I have used this in the past with PowerShell's Extended Type System (ETS) to help with formatting and adding members at the type level rather than using add-member, but I'd really like to be able to limit parameters to functions and scripts by specifying these "meta-types" as the type of parameter.

With the example I gave above, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
Param([MDS__COMPUTER]$comp)
```

and have PowerShell check to see if the $comp object passed in had that in its TypeNames collection.

Is this possible somehow?  I'd like to avoid generating real C# classes and copying the data from the datarow objects (or PSObjects) to new objects.

I should mention that using a type that doesn't exist as a real type causes an error.

Comment: Have you tried using `ValidateScript` as a parameter property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.adamtheautomator.com/building-custom-object-types-powershell-pstypename/), the following solution seems to work (not sure what version of PowerShell is required). Adding a property of PSTypeName to the PSCustomObject causes it to be recognized as that type:

```
$widget = [pscustomobject]@{
    PSTypeName = 'Widget'
    Color = $null
    Size = $null
}

function Get-Something
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param
        (
            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [PSTypeName('Widget')]$Widget
        )
 
        $Widget
}
```

It turns out this works fine if you adjust the TypeNames() array on an existing object (which is what I was looking for):

```
$x=get-service BITS
$x.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'Widget')

Get-Something $x
```

Comment: Setting a TypeName can be done by using this shortcut syntax: `$myObject = [PsCustomObject] @{ PsTypeName = 'My.Object'; Name = 'myName' }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use ValidateScript in the Parameter declaration to check if the TypeNames collection has the TypeName we're looking for. This is how i would do it:

```
function MyFunction
{
    Param
    (
        # Parameter that accepts custom TypeName
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
                   Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({$_.PSObject.TypeNames -contains 'MyType'})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $Comp
    )

    # YOUR CODE HERE
    return $comp

}
```

Comment: I think he can even just do `{$_ -is [MDS__COMPUTER]}` for his validation script.